# UIWebview rendering iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

Could you explain the behavior of `UIWebView -loadHTMLString:baseURL:`?

For example I've got a simple html, which i want to render:

```
<html>
<body>
  Test message <br>
  <img src="%http_path_for_unreachable_resource%" />
</body>
</html>
```

In previous versions of SDK (equal or less then 6.x) `UIWebView` renders this html and shows `'Test message'` without waiting for complete loading of all resources in html.

In 7.0 beta SDK behavior has been changed. Now where is no way to show any content in `UIWebView` without full loading of all resources. So I see a blank white screen without `'Test message'`. Some time later then request for unreachable resource fails with timeout, `UIWebview` show its content.

I have already tried to force show content by using javascript in `-stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString`, by calling `-setNeedsDisplay` for all subviews of `UIWebView`.

Is possible to get an old rendering behavior of `UIWebView`?

Comment: @Shamatlay Did you get solution to get old rendering behavior of UIWebview in iOS 7?

Comment: @DesertRose, in iOS7 beta 5 rendering behavior has been restored

Comment: @ShmatlayAndrey I dont think so.I have to modify css separately or iOS7.

Comment: Are you subclassing `UIWebView`?